# Send email from netezza Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, netezza

I trying to send a queried data through mail from inside a **netezza stored procedure**.
It seems I could send the mail via shell command, but is there any way to send the mail through stored procedure itself.

TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this chunk SQLServer DB:

```
declare @table1 varchar(max)
set @table1 = cast (
(
select 2 [@cellpadding],
       0 [@cellspacing],
       1 [@border],
(
select (select convert(varchar, COL-1) for xml path('td'),type),
       (select convert(varchar, COL-2) for xml path('td'),type),
       (select convert(varchar, COL-3) for xml path('td'),type),
       (select convert(varchar, COL-4) for xml path('td'),type),
       (select convert(varchar, COL-5) for xml path('td'),type),
       (select convert(varchar, COL-6) for xml path('td'),type)
  from #updates
for xml path ('tr'),type 
) 
 for xml path('table'), type
)
as varchar(max))

set @EmailRecipient = 'E-Mail Addresses'
set @MessageSubject = 'Subject'
set @MessageBody =
'<strong>'+@MessageSubject+'</strong><br><br>'+
@table1;

EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Any Short Msg',
    @recipients = @EmailRecipient,
    @subject = @MessageSubject,
    @body = @MessageBody,
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Here are some link from google, might help you on this.

https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/forums/html/topic?id=d2b1272b-9690-4b0b-ae0c-9e81bf4be444

https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=27346

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sending-smtp-mail-using-a-stored-procedure

http://www.serkey.com/tag/sendmail-cfg-netezza/

Comment: As I am trying to send mail from Netezza DB , could you share any idea on netezza

Comment: The first blog , I have already visited which deals with some UDF function which I cant find much information. Since its an UDF function, I am not certain that whether its an inbuilt function of netezza DB. The next blog which deals with writing the list in excel and sending which we already tried an executed via shell command.

Comment: The rest of the link I cant find much helpful. Do let me know if there is any other possibility or could you let me know some info on this UDF function _cf_utl_exec